# How do I get Django rest framework to respect the "required=false" designation in my serializer?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, required

I'm using djangorestframework==3.12.2 .  I have this Serializer.  Some fields, like "desc_english" I don't want to be required ...

```
class ValidateNewCoopSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    coop_name=serializers.CharField()
    street=serializers.CharField()
    address_public=serializers.CharField()
    city=serializers.CharField()
    state=serializers.CharField()
    zip=serializers.CharField()
    county=serializers.CharField()
    country=serializers.CharField()
    websites=serializers.CharField()
    contact_name=serializers.CharField()
    contact_name_public=serializers.CharField()
    contact_email=serializers.CharField()
    contact_email_public=serializers.CharField()
    contact_phone=serializers.CharField()
    contact_phone_public=serializers.CharField()
    scope=serializers.CharField()
    tags=serializers.CharField(required=False)
    desc_english=serializers.CharField(required=False)
    desc_other=serializers.CharField(required=False)
    req_reason=serializers.CharField()
```

which is used in my views.py file like so

```
@api_view(('POST',))
def save_to_sheet_from_form(request):
    """
    This is supposed to write to a Google sheet given a form coming from
    the client.
    """
    valid_ser = ValidateNewCoopSerializer(data=request.data)
    if valid_ser.is_valid():
        post_data = valid_ser.validated_data
        ...
        return Response(post_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(valid_ser.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I notice, though, that when I submit requests, the fields are mark as not required are coming back with errors ...

```
curl 'http://localhost:8000/save_to_sheet_from_form/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Referer: http://localhost:3001/' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:3001' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --data-raw '{"coop_name":"","street":"","address_public":"no","city":"","state":"IL","zip":"","county":"","country":"US","websites":"","contact_name":"","contact_name_public":"no","contact_email":"","contact_email_public":"no","contact_phone":"","contact_phone_public":"no","scope":"local","tags":"","desc_english":"","desc_other":"","req_reason":"add"}'
```

results in

```
{"coop_name":["This field may not be blank."],"street":["This field may not be blank."],"city":["This field may not be blank."],"zip":["This field may not be blank."],"county":["This field may not be blank."],"websites":["This field may not be blank."],"contact_name":["This field may not be blank."],"contact_email":["This field may not be blank."],"contact_phone":["This field may not be blank."],"tags":["This field may not be blank."],"desc_english":["This field may not be blank."],"desc_other":["This field may not be blank."]}
```

How do I configure my serializer so that these fields are actually not required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set `required=False` on the serializer fields. This means that if you don't supply the key for them in the request it will work, **but** if you *do* supply the key then they *would* be validated. Looking at your request you pass `"desc_english":""`, i.e. you do supply the key with an empty string, hence that error is correct. You can set [`allow_blank=True` [DRF docs]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield) on the field if you want to allow empty strings:

```
desc_english=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
```

If you may want to pass null values (`None` in python) to the field you can also set [`allow_null` [DRF docs]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#allow_null) to `True`:

```
desc_english=serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, allow_null=True)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I feel like "required=false" should signify no validation checking at all but I guess "required" means different things to different people.